# Nagios - How to display specific monitors for a specific user/contactgroup while these monitors will also be displayed to the Admin team?

Tags: nagios

I have a Nagios server which monitors many servers, a number of the servers is used for QA matters.
I'd like to allow the QA team access to the Nagios UI and i want them to be able to view only monitors which are related to their work.
More than that, these servers which i want the QA team to monitor should be displayed for the admins group as well (as it is configured at the moment) in addition to the QA team.
Is that doable?

At the moment, the QA are able to see all hosts/services which are configured on Nagios and not only the ones i specified in hosts.cfg which is what i'm trying to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users are only able to see hosts (and the associated services) for which they are contacts.

If you make your 'admins' group the default contact for hosts/services (e.g., in your base templates), you can then add the QA team as contacts to the hosts that you want them to see.

See the [CGI authorization docs](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/cgiauth.html) for more-detailed info on who can see what, and also the [Inheritance docs](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectinheritance.html), specifically the section on "additive inheritance".

Answer (score 0):

1. Configure the QA team are contacts of the related hosts/services
2. List all member of admins group in the
   [`authorized_`](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/configcgi.html)
   variables:

   **`/usr/local/nagios/etc/cgi.cfg`**

   ```
   authorized_for_system_information=admin1,admin2
   authorized_for_configuration_information=admin1,admin2
   authorized_for_system_commands=admin1,admin2
   authorized_for_all_services=admin1,admin2
   authorized_for_all_hosts=admin1,admin2
   authorized_for_all_service_commands=admin1,admin2
   authorized_for_all_host_commands=admin1,admin2
   ```